# What software is required for compiling Matlab mex file from Fortran Silver-frost FTN95 project?

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex, silverfrost-fortran

I want to call Fortran subroutines from Matlab and get the output from them. I'm using Windows 7 x64 and Matlab R2021b.

I have tried compiling in Matlab using mex command.
At

```
mex -setup FORTRAN
```

I have choosen Intel Parallel Studio XE 2019 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

In mex settings: 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2021b\bin\win64\mexopts\intel_fortran_19_vs2015.xml' I have removed \fixed option from COMPFLAGS.
It appeared that it is not able to recognise f95 files:

```
Unknown file extension '.f95'.
```

After changing extension of fortran files from f95 to f90 and trying to compile I got error:

```
error
#5078: Unrecognized token '@' skipped
    result_logic = FEXISTS@(filename,errorcode)
```

I'm not sure if this is the problem of compiler, which is probably not supporting Silver-frost FTN95, or I have to include FTN95 Library in some way.

Comment: `@` is not a legal character in Fortran. It was used by some compilers for some highly non-standard practices, but if you are using such code, you are on your own and you have to depend on compilers that support that.

Comment: If the code is written using FTN95-specific features, you’ll have to compile with the FTN95 compiler.